# C++ executable, sh 1:not found

Tags: c++, linux, system, executable, ros

I created a c++ programm that works with ros. The first step would be to open a roscore in a terminal and move on from there. I do so with `system("roscore &");`

I compiled my file and can run it just fine with ./file.

However, I want to be able to run it as an application (double click). I created a .desktop file and the program shows up in my application list. When i start it though, all I get is a terminal that opens with the message

> sh: 1: roscore: not found
>
> etc.

The same applies for the roslaunch commands. I also fork and exec a roslaunch command, which does not work as well.

I tried `system("ls");` which worked. All cout messages work as well.

Any idea what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

roscore executable is not located in std paths (/bin:/usr/bin:). Use the absolute path - `system("/path/to/roscore &")`

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue.
However the error is a differnt one now, Roscore includes "from rosmaster.master_api import NUM_WORKERS", which cannot be found.
No module named rosmaster.master_api.

Comment: system("cd /path/to/roscore; ./roscore &") You should read some basic shell manuals ;)